# Homomorphisms from $C_2\times C_3$ to $S_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups, group-homomorphism

How many homomorphisms are there from $C_2\times C_3$ to $S_4$ are there? (Using kernel and image to describe).

My thoughts/attempt: Determine homomorphisms by the image of the domain's generators. We know that the order of a map $\varphi(x)$ divides the order of $x$. We take every element in the first $C_2 \times C_3$ and map it to something.
I'm guessing since 2 and 3 are relatively prime, $C_2\times C_3\cong C_6$ and we map every element of the cyclic group of order 6 to elements of the same order in $S_4$. But not sure where to go from here!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Gary I'm not really sure where to start.

Comment: @Gary Just updated it with some thoughts/what I'm beginning to attempt.

Answer (score 4):

There is no element of order $6$ in $S_4$. You can verify this by thinking about the cycle structure of the elements of $S_4$.

Therefore, you may as well just look for non-trivial homomorphisms from $C_2$ to $S_4$, and from $C_3$ to $S_4$.

For $C_2=\{1,x\}$, the generator $x$ has to be sent to an element of order $2$, and there are $9$ of them.

For $C_3=\{1,y,y^2\}$, the generator $y$ has to be sent to a $3$-cycle. The number of $3$-cycles is ${4\choose 3}\times 2=8$.

Then there is the trivial homomorphism.

So $9+8+1=18$.

Comment: So where would we start there? Like, C2 = <1,x>, and we send the generator x somewhere?

Comment: answer edited for details

Comment: Your remark about elements of order $6$ gets around the issue, but it's worth noting that elements of order $2$ in $S_4$ don't need to be $2$-cycles.

Comment: @RaviFernando In fact, there are 9 elements of order 2 in S4. Why don't these get counted in the homomorphisms?

Comment: oh sorry, my mistake, I'll edit it again