# Finding the number of the group homomorphisms $G\to S_4$ ($|G|=6$) by group actions.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, symmetric-groups, group-homomorphism

A homomorphism from a group $G$ of order $6$ to $S_4$ is equivalent to an action of $G$ on the set $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$. By the orbit-stabilizer theorem, every orbit must have size either $1$, or $2$, or $3$ (because $4\nmid 6$). Therefore, the only allowed orbit equations are:

1. $\space\space\space 4 = 1+1+1+1$
2. $\space\space\space4 = 2+1+1$
3. $\space\space\space4 = 2+2$
4. $\space\space\space4 = 3+1$

Am I right if I consider as *upper bound* of the number in the title the number of ways the orbit equations 1 to 4 can actually be realized? I mean:

1 can be realized in the only way:
$$\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\}\}$$
2 in the following $6$ ways:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&\{\{1,2\},\{3\},\{4\}\} \\
&\{\{1,3\},\{2\},\{4\}\} \\
&\{\{1,4\},\{2\},\{3\}\} \\
&\{\{2,3\},\{1\},\{4\}\} \\
&\{\{2,4\},\{1\},\{3\}\} \\
&\{\{3,4\},\{1\},\{2\}\} \\
\end{alignat}
3 in the following $6$ ways:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\} \\
&\{\{1,3\},\{2,4\}\} \\
&\{\{1,4\},\{2,3\}\} \\
&\{\{2,3\},\{1,4\}\} \\
&\{\{2,4\},\{1,3\}\} \\
&\{\{3,4\},\{1,2\}\} \\
\end{alignat}
and 4 in the following $4$ ways:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&\{\{2,3,4\},\{1\}\} \\
&\{\{1,3,4\},\{2\}\} \\
&\{\{1,2,4\},\{3\}\} \\
&\{\{1,2,3\},\{4\}\} \\
\end{alignat}
So, I'd say that there are *at most* $1+6+6+4=17$ homomorphisms as in the title (the trivial one included), but according to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4407558/1007416) (where $G=C_2\times C_3$) this conclusion is wrong. Does it mean that distinct actions can have one same orbit setup?

Comment: If your group has any non-trivial automorphisms (and every group of order${}>2$ has them) then one can always compose a group action with such an automorphism to obtain a group action with the same orbits that has no particular reason to be the same group action (though sometimes it will nonetheless be the same). For instance a cyclic group of order $3$ or $6$ can act in two distinct ways transitively on three elements, while for the symmetic group $\mathbf S_3$ there are $6$ distinct such actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed distinct actions can have the same orbits. For instance, on any group left multiplication $a_g(h)=gh$ and inverse right multiplication $b_g(h)=hg^{-1}$ are two potentially different actions, and they both have the entire group as one orbit.